# Spring Boot exception while trying to send email:java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to use spring boot start mail to send an email.

Exception happends in Junit
here is my code:

EmailServiceApp.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class EmailServiceApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EmailServiceApp.class, args);
    }

}
```

Email.java

```
@Component
public class Email {

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSender; 
    private String from;
    private String[] to;
    private String[] cc;
    private String subject;
    private String text;
    private List<File> attachList; 

    public Email(String from,String[] to,String subject,String text){
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.text = text;

    }

    public String getFrom() {
        return from;
    }

    public void setFrom(String from) {
        this.from = from;
    }

    public String[] getTo() {
        return to;
    }

    public void setTo(String[] to) {
        this.to = to;
    }

    public String[] getCc() {
        return cc;
    }
    public void setCc(String[] cc) {
        this.cc = cc;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
    public List<File> getAttachList() {
        return attachList;
    }

    public void setAttachList(List<File> attachList) {
        this.attachList = attachList;
    }

    public void sendEmail(){
        MimeMessage message = null;
        try {
            message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
            MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
            helper.setFrom(this.from);
            helper.setTo(this.to);
            helper.setCc(this.cc);
            helper.setSubject(this.subject);
            helper.setText(this.text);
            if(this.attachList.size()!=0){
                for (File attFile : attachList) {
                    helper.addAttachment(attFile.getName(), attFile);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mailSender.send(message);
    }

}
```

Tester class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class SpringBootEmailSenderTester {

    @Test
    public void sendAttachmentsMail() {
        //Even the void method
    }

}
```

When I try to run as Junit test,exception:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.****.Email required a bean of type 'java.lang.String' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'java.lang.String' in your configuration.
2017-08-02 10:53:14 [main] ERROR TestContextManager:234 - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@291373d3] to prepare test instance [com.***.SpringBootEmailSenderTester@372ca2d6]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) ~[spring-test-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83) ~[spring-test-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:189) ~[spring-test-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:131) ~[spring-test-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230) [spring-test-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
```

Why? How can I fix that? I want to use email.sendEmail in my tester class code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `Email` class is a Spring-managed bean (due to it being annotated with `@Component`). This means that Spring is responsible for creating an instance of the class. To do that it needs to pass in something for the four constructor arguments. It can't do that as there are no beans of the required type.

Having an `Email` class that is a bean is rather unusual. Instead I would expect a bean that knows how to send an `Email`. Your application creates `Email` instances and uses the bean to send them. The bean would contain your existing `sendEmail` method modified to take an `Email` as an argument.

Comment: Thank you very much.I've changed my codes and it works.